# Differences between past simple + future simple /future in the past

Tags: grammar, sequence-of-tenses

Let's consider the following sentences :

> He didn't know that we will soon buy a new house.
>   He didn't know that we would soon buy a new house.

I believe that both of them are gramatically correct, but they express different things.
In the first case the action refers to the future i.e. he wasn't aware that in the near future we are going to buy a new house. The second one has the same meaning, but in this case the action of buying the house is in the past i.e. we have already bought it. I would like to know if I am right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- He didn't know that we will soon buy a new house. [buzzer]
- He didn't know that we would soon buy a new house. [good]
- **He didn't know we were going to buy** a new house. [all past: good]
- **He didn't know we intended** to buy a new house. [all past: good]

That's said, I would say:

- He **didn't know** the moon **looks** red at that time of year. [past + present: OK]
- He **didn't know** the moon **looked** red at that time of year.

So, simple past plus present is OK. Simple past plus **will** is not standard.

Simple past in the main clause pretty much forecloses the use of **will** in the second.

Please note: 
**He didn't know we would soon buy a new house**.

says nothing about whether or not a house was actually bought. If the house had been bought, the sentence would be:

**He didn't know we bought a new house OR had bought a new house**.

Comment: I would add that use of simple past + future might be colloquial. You will hear English-speakers use it but it would be frowned upon even in casual oral English.

Comment: @urnonav No, it is not colloquial. It is agrammatical.

Comment: @Lambie thank you! So, by using "would" instead of "will", does the sentence still imply that the action of buying the house may not have happened yet?

Comment: @Lambie, I'm not arguing the ungrammatical characterisation. I do hear native English speakers mix and match quite often (much to the chagrin of my somewhat obsessive mind).

Comment: @urnonav Yes, they mix and match but this would not be a usual one **at all**.

Comment: @Lambie, I am thinking of sentences like these: "I didn't know the flight won't leave till 5" or "I didn't realise you will have to travel next week." When the event continues to be in the future, I am not so sure native speakers wouldn't throw in a simple future. Would you please enlighten me why you are so convinced otherwise?

Comment: @urnonav But the event does not continue to be in the future....I didn't know [the flight left or didn't leave] or [would leave]. Most even half-educated speakers would say those. They simply wouldn't say; I didn't know the flight will leave. The reason I know is because I listen to native speakers all day long, day in and day out. That said, weird things happen in interviews, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are quite correct, with one small nuance.

> He didn't know that we would soon buy a new house.

This most likely refers to an event (the house purchase) that is already in the past, as the question described. But it could be part of a hypothetical sequence in which the purchase never took place, but had things gone differently it would have happened in the alternate past.